# Ubuntu randomly started blinking the screen on boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, gnome

I used my Ubuntu Desktop yesterday as usual, but now I can't boot in because the screen keeps flickering to a black screen and a verbose boot screen where I see no failure or errors. I can ALT-F2 and see the login, but it stills flickers so I can't type correctly my password. I didn't install anything particular, I've searched a little and people talk about NVIDIA drivers, but I didn't install anything like this yesterday, what can I do?

Thanks for helping.

`dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii` returns

```
 nvidia-375               375.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
 nvidia-opencl-icd-375    375.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
 nvidia-prime             0.8.2
 nvidia-settings          361.42-0ubuntu1
```

Comment: is it the computer causing the problem or Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu, I have a dual-boot, Windows works just fine.

Comment: try to ssh login to it and see what happens

Comment: can you log in?

Comment: No, I can't it flickers infinitely

Comment: do you have grub?

Comment: Yes, I do have grub

Comment: does grub work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62458/discussion-between-drakota-and-camden).

Comment: Might be due to lightdm display manager. This might help:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Uninstall the Windows driver that allows you to read/write to Ubuntu EXT4 partitions.
2. To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

- boot to the GRUB menu
- select Ubuntu
- hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key
- use arrow keys to move
- find the line that has "quiet splash"
- add `nomodeset`, so "quiet splash nomodeset"
- hit <kbd>F10</kbd> to exit and continue boot
- see if it flickers

**Update #2:**

Your recently installed Nvidia driver is causing your problem. In maintenance mode, uninstall/purge all `*nvidia*` software, reboot, then use `Software & Updates`, `Additional Drivers` tab, to reinstall Nvidia **tested** version, then reboot.

Comment: I don't think this is it, I had the same problem before installing the driver to read my Linux partition, I installed it like 10 min ago to get some files onto my Windows partition.

Comment: @Drakota did you perform the `fsck`?

Comment: Yes and I didn't get any error messages and I still get the flickering.

Comment: Did it flicker when you did the `fsck`? Do you have Nvidia?

Comment: No, I didn't get any flickering.

Comment: Do you have Nvidia? If so, what version? From the Ubuntu repos, or Nvidia web site?

Comment: I'm not sure about the specific version, but I used the one in the Software & Updates tab and I choose the first proprietary one.

Comment: Go back to the # prompt and type `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii` and copy/paste results into your question.

Comment: Do Update #1. Report back.

Comment: Tried Update #1 still flickering unfortunately

Comment: With nomodeset, I've managed to access the terminal using CTRL+ALT F2. Tried doing update upgrade dist-upgrade nothing changed

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the blinking screen on a dual boot Ubuntu 18 and Windows 10 machine and the boot sequence seemed to be stuck. When I tried CTRL+ALT+DEL a message was displayed that `unattended updates` was in progress. At some point the blinking stopped and a finished message appeared. The machine rebooted, and everything was normal after that.

Answer (score 1):

I installed `bumblebee-nvidia` in a terminal session and was able to login. Still haven't figured what happened in the first place, but at least it works for now. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: For what it's worth, I installed bumblebee just now, rebooted and there was no blinking display. It had just started to do that a few updates ago, so I have no idea which one caused it as I often put the computer to sleep at night.

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem today. My Ubuntu 18.04 had been working like forever, but today it wouldn't allow me to ssh into. A reboot paused somewhere with no apparent errors, with screening flickering. Pressing <kbd>ALT+F2</kbd> showed the login prompt, but with screening flickering, no matter how fast I typed, the login was not correct.

In the end, it turned out **it's my root partition was full**. A specific program was generating data continuously and filled up the partition.

The quickest way to free up more space would be go to recovery mode in GRUB, then go to the root shell.