# Ubuntu 16.04 Boot Screen Flickers without `nomodeset` but then freezes

Tags: boot, freeze

First of all, I have lost my system access and I am posting from my mobile. So please forgive any formatting problems, I will edit the question properly once I get my system access back.

I was using my Ubuntu 16.04 without any problem for quite some time and suddenly this happened. My boot screen was flickering just like in this thread: [Ubuntu randomly started blinking the screen on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/937712/ubuntu-randomly-started-blinking-the-screen-on-boot)

I am not able to login.

I dont have any nvidia hardware with me, neither have I installed any of their software.

I ran `fsck`, there was no errors shown. I tried booting with `nomodeset`, then screen doesn't flicker, but the booting stops at the below screen.

[image]

At this point, I am able to open a terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. I am able to login there. If I enter the command `startx`, this is happening.

[image]

Just before the last shut down, I have added `bitcoin-core` PPA, installed `bitcoin-core`, then uninstalled `bitcoin-core` and then removed the PPA. Then I have installed Electrum wallet from Software Centre. I removed it since it was not launching. Then I installed the `snap` version of the same wallet. Then also it was not launching. Then I shut down the machine. And I am not able to boot back.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ideas:

First:
The error complains about possibly being out of space. You can attempt to recover space by booting into recovery mode from the grub menu and selecting "clean".

You can also attempt to boot into the command line and remove unused packages by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

While in command line, you can also navigate through and delete any documents/pictures/videos etc. you don't need in attempt to clear even more space.

Useful links for the above mentioned ideas:

http://ask.xmodulo.com/boot-into-command-line-ubuntu-debian.html

https://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/

Second:
Try starting without nomodeset. For me, I only need to use nomodeset during install, after I update all of my drivers it is no longer necessary.

Comment: thanks. seems like deleting files and  failsafex did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> as you did before. Rather than `startx` though use this command to clean up any `bitcoin` install/removal problems:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

If errors are found and fixed you should be able to reboot normally. If some errors can't be fixed, post a comment on them.