# Screen tearing/flickering on Lenovo Ideapad 720S 131IKB

Tags: 18.04, lenovo

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 16.10 or 18.04 (would prefer 18.04 as it will end up having longer LTS). The issue has been the screen tearing that accompanies the Linux System after install. [I have attached a video showing the display issues.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIDZUjcsm6U)

The tearing only starts once I've booted into Ubuntu; the OS selection menu is perfectly fine.

Specs:

```
Model: Lenovo Ideapad 720S 13IKB
CPU: Intel 8550U
RAM: 8GB
Display: 4K
```

I've tried adding the [xorg config files](https://www.pcsuggest.com/fix-linux-screen-tearing/), but that has led to nothing, unfortunately.

I've tried altering the default resolution and refresh rates as well, but same results.

I have updated the BIOS on my laptop using the Lenovo Update tools in Windows.

I'm at a loss, any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having the same flickering issue.

Comment: I have had absolutely no luck. I'm able to run Ubuntu 18.04 on my desktop thankfully and can use that when needed for school.

Comment: That's unfortunate! I've been trying various solutions I've found around the internet without luck. I have Ubuntu on lots of different machines and this is the first time I've not been able to get things working right. Screen flickering this badly is something I can't ignore though. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and following this guide made it work for me:

- boot to the GRUB menu
- select Ubuntu
- hit the e key
- use arrow keys to move
- find the line that has "quiet splash"
- add nomodeset, so "quiet splash nomodeset"
- hit F10 to exit and continue boot
- see if it flickers

If you want to make it permanent you can edit the grub file by opening a terminal and doing this:

- sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash nomodeset" then exit the gedit
- sudo update-grub
- reboot

The original guide I read was here:
[Ubuntu randomly started blinking the screen on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/937712/ubuntu-randomly-started-blinking-the-screen-on-boot)