# How to solve the flickering of splash screen in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, startup

From quite recently my splash screen has started continuously flashing upon boot with command lines.[Have a look at this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYO74MfOxrQ)

Comment: Are you running from liveUSB? do you checked https://askubuntu.com/questions/937712/ubuntu-randomly-started-blinking-the-screen-on-boot?

Comment: no, im not running from a usb

Answer (score 1):

The messages that show in between your splash screen are messages that the kernel thinks are important for you to see. It is advised to take note and see if the cause of these messages can be tackled. That might be difficult though, and if your system is otherwise fine when booted, you can just choose to ignore these messages, and not have them appear by changing the log level.

To eliminate display of any kernel messages during boot, proceed as follows:

- Open the file `/etc/default/grub` as root user with your text editor.
  If you use `nano`, you can open the file as root with the command `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
- Change the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` to include the option `loglevel=0`. For example, in a default Ubuntu install, the line might look like:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Change it to read:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet loglevel=0 splash"`

Save the file and exit the editor (in case of `nano`, <kbd>Ctrl+s</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd> will do.)

- Update your grub to reflect the changes with the command `sudo update-grub`