# Cannot use any app, Display error, Error in graphic card defination

Tags: drivers, graphics, display, laptop, intel-graphics

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04LTS on my laptop and I face this problem:
After log into my user as "Ubuntu System" I can only see desktop and if I tried to open any app or do any action system freezes and nothing happen, but if I logged in as "Wayland System" I can use show and use some apps, But if I tried to open apps like "Firefox, Chromium or another apps" The same problem happen.

**Update:**
I tried to solve it by doing these steps:

- Changing "grub" `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` Parameter by adding `nomodeset` after `quiet splash`, Finally line changed to:

  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"

Now I can use Ubuntu normally but I lost the "brightness controller" and I cannot change brightness level.
I think that Graphics card isn't defined, how to solve this problem?

**Note:** `VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? There are 2 that would be considered latest release. 20.04 LTS and 20.10

Comment: It's 20.04, the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem could be with video driver /GPU. Pls mention your PC's hardware configurations. If you've Nvidia then try switching to intel's one.
Press **ctrl** + **alt** + **f2** then login and then issue the following commands
Check which graphics is running:

```
prime-select query
```

if it shows Nvidia etc then Switch to intel-

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

if none of above works, then try uninstalling Nvidia-

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
```

Reboot

if problem persists try option1 here : [askubuntu.com/a/937727/905106](https://askubuntu.com/a/937727/905106)

Comment: I selected intel but the problem keeps on, my video card is intel not Nvidia

Comment: Have you tried : `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`  if problem persists try option1 here : https://askubuntu.com/a/937727/905106

Comment: Option one worked, and the problem has solved.

Comment: accept this as answer if it helped